# How many people could be wrong in telling a coin?

Tags: probability

If we have two coins of radius of $R_1=8$ and $R_2=12$. Assume that 99% of people will be able to tell the size within $\pm5\%$ by touch it only, and assume it is a normal distribution.

Question A: How many people will mistakenly think a given coin is the other one.

Question B: If insert a third coin in between in a average radius, how many people make the mistakes for each coin?

Question C: If insert n coins in between with same step of change, what will be the worst case? (It must be a function of n, right?)

If the question does not make sense, please let me know.

Comment: This is actually a linguistic problem. For this simplified version, I think is a integration over p(x). And should we assume that, if one think it is less than 10, then the result is 8. Correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what question C means... I've put my answer for parts A and B the best I understand what it is asking.

Comment: @user103828 C means, say if n = 3, then set of R = {8,9,10,11,12}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that if the coin has radius $R_j$ then the distribution of size that people feel is normal with mean $\mu=R_j$ and standard deviation $\sigma\approx\frac{0.05 R_j}{2.5}=0.02R_j$ (I get the standard deviation because I know that $99\%$ of people can tell the size within $5\%$ so $0.05 R_j$ is $2.5$ standard deviations away from the mean.

Hence, when $R_1=8$ then distribution is approximately $N(8,\sigma=0.16)$ and when $R_2=12$ then the distribution is approximately $N(12,\sigma=0.24)$ and when  $R_3=10$ then approximately $N(10,\sigma=0.2)$ so the answers to $A$ and $B$ are $0\%$ (or very close to it).

Let us say that there are $n$ coins between $8$ and $12$ and the distance between each coin is $(12-8)/(n-1)$. Also assume that people who get a number closer to $R_{i}$ choose $R_i$ and the real coin, for example, is $R_j=12$ then in general the number of people who guess incorrectly is 
$$P(\textrm{closer to }R_i|\textrm{real coin } R_j=12) \approx P(\textrm{get number} \leq  12-\frac{2.5}{n-1}|N(12,0.24)) \approx \Psi(-\frac{10}{n-1})$$

Comment: By saying 2.5, do you 2.575 829 ...     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: Yes. I was approximating...

Comment: Is it possible to know if give a 10 to 1,000,000 people, how many would say 8 or 12? What would be a math explanation of it.

Comment: See modification above... the question is almost a good one but it's still unclear what exactly to assume the distribution of guesses is and when people guess incorrectly... also the numbers seem a little weird.